# How to center background image in any screen size if text is center-aligned?

Tags: css, background-image, alignment

How do you align a background icon image if the text is center-aligned? Like a small icon before the text. If it's not center-aligned, I can use something like:

```
p { 
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

But if I center align it like so:

```
p { 
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The background remains on the left corner while the text is centered (so there's a huge gap in between them). It's possible to use background position, however, if the screen is of a different size than what I use, the background will be overlapped by the text.

You can check the jsFiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/PvL3T/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:first-letter` pseudo element will play around good, http://jsfiddle.net/PvL3T/7/

```
p { 
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.resize:first-letter { 
   background: url(http://www.torontorawveganfestival.com/Images/Pen-icon.png) no-repeat 0 50%; padding-left: 20px;
}
```

this will work even into IE6 if you care, but only if there is white space between selector and opening curve bracket. Only for IE6 something like this `p:first-letter{...` will not work, but `p:first-letter {...` will

and just in similar way, you may use `:first-line`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to have the icon float inline next to the text, you might want to consider placing it inside the parent tag. Then the background image can float alongside the text regardless of screen size:

http://jsfiddle.net/PvL3T/4/

HTML:

```
<p><i class="icon"></i>This is a text that is center aligned.</p>
```

CSS:

```
p { 
    text-align: center;
}

p .icon {
    background: url(http://www.torontorawveganfestival.com/Images/Pen-icon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an line-block displayed element before your text. So it can go with your text content. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PvL3T/5/

```
.icon
{
    background: url(http://www.torontorawveganfestival.com/Images/Pen-icon.png) no-repeat center center;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center;
```

or alternatively:

```
background-position: center;
```